# Exit when checkbox is ticked, if not, don't exit script (tkinter, python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyautogui, customtkinter

I'm making a tkinter app for my python script. I want to make sure that when the user ticks the "Auto exit" checkbox, the script will automatically exit when done - closing the gui app.

But if the user does **not** tick this box, then the script will stop as usual, but the gui app will remain open. I am using an open source base for the gui because I think it looks nice. This is mostly just for personal use and experimental purposes.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Code:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import webbrowser
import pyautogui

def main_script():
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')
    pyautogui.moveTo(500, 500)
# this is where I want the script to stop, but the gui app remaining open if checkbox is ticked. 
# If not, then everything will close.

self.check_box_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=self.frame_right,
                                                     text="Auto exit")
        self.check_box_1.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=20, padx=40, sticky="w")
```

Comment: Simply call `self.check_box_1.get()` to check whether the checkbox is checked or not inside `main_script()`, then do whatever you want based on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command which sets a variable, then check that variable at the end of `main_script`.

```
auto_exit = False
auto_exit_var = tkinter.IntVar()

def main_script():
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')
    pyautogui.moveTo(500, 500)
    if auto_exit:
        root.destroy() # Replace root with your window name

def toggle_auto_exit():
    global auto_exit
    auto_exit = auto_exit_var.get() == 1


self.check_box_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=self.frame_right, text="Auto exit", variable = auto_exit_var, command = toggle_auto_exit)
self.check_box_1.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=20, padx=40, sticky="w")
```

I've added two global variables, `auto_exit` and `auto_exit_var`. `auto_exit_var` is a Tkinter `IntVar` which keeps track of the check box value. When the check box is pressed it calls `toggle_auto_exit`, which gets the value of the `IntVar` and compares it to 1 (On) and stores that in `auto_exit`.

It looks like you're using a class already so it may be possible to avoid using the global variable. I tested this using a Tkinter `Checkbutton` so I'm not certain the custom Tkinter widget will work the same but it should.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added this to my code, however, it doesn't close the app. Is there anything that could be in the way for my situation?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context. If you can provide a [mre] as an edit to your question that would be useful.